# Setting up an ODBC between access and mySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I've been asked to set up an ODBC connection between an Access database and a mySQL database. I've never done this before and I'm having some difficulty connecting the two together.

My main issue appears to be the server name. I'm prompted by Access to insert the SQL server name along with my details. I host the database and have access to cPanel and phpMyAdmin but I can't seem to find an actual server name anywhere.

Where do I look for the server name or am I missing a vital step here somewhere? Why they've asked a front end dev to do this I wil never know :(

Comment: Is the mysql server public facing or is it all wrapped up behind hosting?

Comment: It's all behind hosting I'm afraid.

Comment: If you can't connect to it using the public IP then its probably not directly accessible, best to talk to your hosting provider.

Comment: I don't know if I can or not because I don't know the IP which is my problem. I don;t know how to find out what it is.

Comment: If its a part of a hosting package try the website ip?

Comment: The web host would have to have exposed a port to the open Internet for you to be able to access it this way, and that would NOT be something you'd want them doing without specifically asking for it (and not something you really should be asking them to do in the first place). This is the kind of thing that should really only be done over a VPN -- opening up a database port to the open Internet is an invitation for every hacker to try to exploit whatever weaknesses your database server has to have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the server IP from within mysql itself.  This may help however

```
SELECT @@global.server_id
```

Which gives you the local server id